# Cannot run new cocos2d-x project

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I tried to solve this problem by own but i don't have more ideas;(
I created with the cocos2d-x console an new project.
Now i want to compile this but alway i get this error(s).
I use actually the newest at bundle for mac, apache-ant-1.9.4 & android NDK-r9d

```
   MacBook-Air:3sCube to-dev$ cocos run -p android -v
Running command: compile
Building mode: debug
building native
NDK build mode: debug
The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !
running: '/Users/to-dev/Desktop/android-ndk-r9d/ndk-build -C /Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android -j1 NDK_MODULE_PATH=/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d:/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos:/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/external NDK_DEBUG=1'

Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/Android.mk:cocos2dxandroid_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
make: Entering directory `/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android'
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocos2d.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocosdenshion.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libchipmunk.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocos2dandroid.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcpufeatures.a
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libcocos2dcpp.so
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCActionManager.cpp:81: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ccArrayNew(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCActionManager.cpp:100: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ccArrayRemoveObjectAtIndex(cocos2d::_ccArray*, int, bool)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCAtlasNode.cpp:93: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::initWithTexture(cocos2d::Texture2D*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCAtlasNode.cpp:138: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::QuadCommand::init(float, unsigned int, cocos2d::GLProgramState*, cocos2d::BlendFunc, cocos2d::V3F_C4B_T2F_Quad*, int, cocos2d::Mat4 const&)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontAtlas.cpp:76: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::Texture2D::initWithData(void const*, int, cocos2d::Texture2D::PixelFormat, int, int, cocos2d::Size const&)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontAtlas.cpp:268: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::Texture2D::initWithData(void const*, int, cocos2d::Texture2D::PixelFormat, int, int, cocos2d::Size const&)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontAtlas.cpp:312: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::Texture2D::initWithData(void const*, int, cocos2d::Texture2D::PixelFormat, int, int, cocos2d::Size const&)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCGrid.cpp:133: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::Texture2D::initWithData(void const*, int, cocos2d::Texture2D::PixelFormat, int, int, cocos2d::Size const&)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCLabel.cpp:1326: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::updateQuad(cocos2d::V3F_C4B_T2F_Quad*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCLabelAtlas.cpp:208: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::increaseTotalQuadsWith(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCLabelAtlas.cpp:219: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::resizeCapacity(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCLabelAtlas.cpp:250: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::updateQuad(cocos2d::V3F_C4B_T2F_Quad*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParallaxNode.cpp:68: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ccArrayNew(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParallaxNode.cpp:126: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ccArrayRemoveObjectAtIndex(cocos2d::_ccArray*, int, bool)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleBatchNode.cpp:100: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::initWithTexture(cocos2d::Texture2D*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleBatchNode.cpp:459: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::fillWithEmptyQuadsFromIndex(int, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleBatchNode.cpp:465: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::moveQuadsFromIndex(int, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleBatchNode.cpp:469: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::increaseTotalQuadsWith(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleBatchNode.cpp:291: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::moveQuadsFromIndex(int, int, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleBatchNode.cpp:379: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::removeQuadsAtIndex(int, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleBatchNode.cpp:382: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::fillWithEmptyQuadsFromIndex(int, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleBatchNode.cpp:433: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::resizeCapacity(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleExamples.cpp:52: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::Image::initWithImageData(unsigned char const*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleSystem.cpp:403: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ZipUtils::inflateMemory(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char**)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleSystem.cpp:409: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::Image::initWithImageData(unsigned char const*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCParticleSystemQuad.cpp:377: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::QuadCommand::init(float, unsigned int, cocos2d::GLProgramState*, cocos2d::BlendFunc, cocos2d::V3F_C4B_T2F_Quad*, int, cocos2d::Mat4 const&)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCRenderTexture.cpp:526: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::Image::initWithRawData(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, bool)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCRenderTexture.cpp:530: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::Image::initWithRawData(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, bool)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSprite.cpp:336: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::Image::initWithRawData(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, bool)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSprite.cpp:568: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::updateQuad(cocos2d::V3F_C4B_T2F_Quad*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSprite.cpp:595: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::QuadCommand::init(float, unsigned int, cocos2d::GLProgramState*, cocos2d::BlendFunc, cocos2d::V3F_C4B_T2F_Quad*, int, cocos2d::Mat4 const&)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSprite.cpp:913: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::updateQuad(cocos2d::V3F_C4B_T2F_Quad*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.cpp:99: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::initWithTexture(cocos2d::Texture2D*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.cpp:548: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::insertQuad(cocos2d::V3F_C4B_T2F_Quad*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.cpp:560: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::removeQuadAtIndex(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.cpp:405: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::resizeCapacity(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.cpp:639: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::insertQuad(cocos2d::V3F_C4B_T2F_Quad*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCTMXLayer.cpp:91: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ccCArrayNew(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCTMXLayer.cpp:448: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ccCArrayInsertValueAtIndex(cocos2d::_ccCArray*, void*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCTMXLayer.cpp:384: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ccCArrayInsertValueAtIndex(cocos2d::_ccCArray*, void*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCTMXLayer.cpp:585: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ccCArrayRemoveValueAtIndex(cocos2d::_ccCArray*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCTMXLayer.cpp:595: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::removeQuadAtIndex(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCTMXLayer.cpp:565: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ccCArrayRemoveValueAtIndex(cocos2d::_ccCArray*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCTMXXMLParser.cpp:646: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::ZipUtils::inflateMemoryWithHint(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char**, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCTileMapAtlas.cpp:226: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::TextureAtlas::increaseTotalQuadsWith(int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./3d/CCBundle3D.cpp:451: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::BundleReader::init(char*, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./3d/CCBundle3D.cpp:456: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::BundleReader::read(void*, int, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./3d/CCBundle3D.cpp:465: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::BundleReader::read(void*, int, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./3d/CCBundle3D.cpp:484: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::BundleReader::read(void*, int, int)'
/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./3d/CCBundle3D.cpp:497: error: undefined reference to 'cocos2d::BundleReader::read(void*, int, int)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/Users/to-dev/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.2/3sCube/proj.android'
Error running command, return code: 2
```

What do i wrong? Thanks for your help!

t333o

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all answers and comments!

My Solution was that i reinstall cocos2d-x 3.2 and all the environmental variables.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you tried to run : cocos run -p android ?

2) Did you check **cocos2d lib** added to the Android.mk ?

3) You can try to use to the following Makefiles:

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := c++_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang

APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -std=c++11 -fsigned-char
APP_LDFLAGS := -latomic


APP_DEBUG := $(strip $(NDK_DEBUG))
ifeq ($(APP_DEBUG),1)
  APP_CPPFLAGS += -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1
  APP_OPTIM := debug
else
  APP_CPPFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
  APP_OPTIM := release
endif
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/MenuScene.cpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS     := -std=c++11
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static

# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosbuilder_static
# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += spine_static
# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocostudio_static
# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_network_static
# LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)
$(call import-module,audio/android)

# $(call import-module,Box2D)
# $(call import-module,editor-support/cocosbuilder)
# $(call import-module,editor-support/spine)
# $(call import-module,editor-support/cocostudio)
# $(call import-module,network)
# $(call import-module,extensions)
```

Comment: I think this were the android.mk files which i use already. Maybe you have another idea?

Comment: Sorry about this idea. But you can try to make a new project: cocos new MyGame -p com.yourcompany.mygame -l cpp -d yourdir , and run the following command into the new project dir : cocos run -p android. This helps you check the link of the cocos2d-x libraries.